# Photos.app is missing the All Photos view / Photos sidebar button

Tags: photos, catalina

This question I think is best served with a screenshot.

In Photos, the sidebar for a new library, basically looks like this:

[image]

Well, for one of my macbooks, it just literally doesn't have the "Photos" option, which is surprisingly annoying given that I don't really need it and can still search by date and place anyway.  But it's driving me nuts.  It's not a hidden menu option or account preference.

Other mac just starts at Memories:

[image]

I've tried many things, and I've narrowed it down to the machine itself:

- I can open a .photoslibrary on one mac, and see Photos.
- Copy the exact same .photoslibrary to this other mac, and not see it.
- This happens on two completely fresh blank formatted Macs
- The .photoslibrary is not tied to any account.
- Same version of Photos.app and Mac OSX.

*Please someone know this*.  This issue does not exist on the web.

Comment: A lot of people seem to have this problem but AFAIK there is no fix. E.g. see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250883814  and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250958933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't occur to me that the machines were not technically supported by this version of macOS.  Booting off exactly the same physical hard disk in a supported machine works fine.

I've not looked deeper into why it does this, only that this has explained it for me and there's no setting I'm missing somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can right click on any photo (e.g. in *Recents*) and select "Show in All Photos".

Photos will then switch to the "All Photos" view and you can use it pretty normally though the entry in the sidebar is still missing.